# Why this code doesn't work property?

Tags: javascript, html, render

Here is my code:

```js
            document.getElementById("charthelp").innerHTML+="<table>";
            for(var i=0; i<data.ertekek.length; i++)
            {
                szinek = [Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1), Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1), Math.floor((Math.random() * 200) + 1)];
                charts[i]=new TimeSeries();
                smoothie.addTimeSeries(charts[i], { strokeStyle: 'rgb('+szinek[0]+', '+szinek[1]+', '+szinek[2]+')', fillStyle: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.0)', lineWidth: 3 });
                if(i%2==1){ document.getElementById("charthelp").innerHTML+= '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="'+i+'", onclick="handleClick(this)"><span style="background-color:rgb('+szinek[0]+', '+szinek[1]+', '+szinek[2]+')">&nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp</span>'+data.ertekek[i].neve+'</input></td>'; }
                else { document.getElementById("charthelp").innerHTML+= '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+i+'", onclick="handleClick(this)"><span style="background-color:rgb('+szinek[0]+', '+szinek[1]+', '+szinek[2]+')">&nbsp  &nbsp &nbsp</span>'+data.ertekek[i].neve+'</input></td></tr>'; }
                inic=true;
            }
            document.getElementById("charthelp").innerHTML+='</table>';
```

Here is the rendered HTML code:

```html
<div id="charthelp"><input type="checkbox" id="0" ,="" onclick="handleClick(this)"><table>
    
</table>
<input type="checkbox" id="1" ,="" onclick="handleClick(this)"><span style="background-color:rgb(109, 12, 20)">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>Elektronikai csarnok
<input type="checkbox" id="2" ,="" onclick="handleClick(this)"><span style="background-color:rgb(92, 148, 103)">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>Bemutatóterem
<input type="checkbox" id="3" ,="" onclick="handleClick(this)"><span style="background-color:rgb(121, 81, 16)">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</span>Fejlesztés
```

And here is a picture of the table: [image: Picture]

As you see the JS code does not work property. It should do it sequentially, but the first and last line runs first. After it the iteration runs. I think it must be a table, but it isn't a table as well...

Comment: try building your HTML string as a variable rather than setting innerHTML directly every time. Just run the innerHTML command once at the end of the process, applying the string you created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that browser automatically add `</table>` after you trying to append `<table>` to document HTML.

Try to use

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
table.appendChild(tr);
...
document.getElementById("charthelp").appendChild(table);
```